# Image alt text not available to inspect element and Google isn't picking it up but it is in the page source

Tags: alt-attribute

My website's image `alt` attributes are missing when I check through Developer Tools: I see no `alt` text. But when I check through  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or view page source, it is showing `alt` text.

When I search for these images in Google with the `alt` text, my website's images are not indexed.

Comment: How long have you waited? This takes quite a while.

Comment: More than four months

Comment: You can try disabling "safe search" or even try using advanced search. If that won't work then change the alt text so its more of what users want while it still is related to your site.

Comment: It'd help if you shared the link to your website. I suspect its either a JavaScript issue removing the ALTS or the tool that your using to inspect the elements. First try both Google Chrome and Firefox 'Inspect' rather than just one browser and use a browser plugin to disable JS and then inspect it. Additionally... Googe images is mega slow at ranking images, sometimes it may never rank them if they have too many with similar keywords... link plz.

Comment: alt text isn't even a good way to rank images for keywords.   In my experience it is much better to enclose the image in a div with some text:  `<div><img src="..."> Description of image</div>`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Very interesting observation. Have you seen quicker or better img search indexing that way or how did it perform better than the ALT?

Comment: @Kristian You get better image search rankings when users can see the text on the page associated with the image.

Answer (score 1):

As first, to become sure, whether Google makes indeed notice about your images, make use of "fetch as Google" function in your Search Console.

If on fetching as Google `alt` are in the place, do the next check: make a `site` query into Google web search, open `cache`-version of your page and look into the source code - are `alt`there in the place?

If both tests are positive - than just wait, make an image sitemap, share it into Search Console, than wait again - you had make doubly sure, that technically everything is ok.

If `alt` aren't there at fetching as Google - seems to be as @Stephen Ostermiller wrote, they could be delivered by javascript and you should debug, whats wrong with it.